# Evaluating the supremum of a function as n tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Problem:** Let $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuos function such that $g(1)=0$. Show that $\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|x^ng(x)|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

**My approach:** Let $f(x)=x^ng(x)$. Then, $f(x)$ is continuos on $[0,1]$. Using the extreme value theorem we can say, that $|f(x)|$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and attains its bounds, i.e., $\exists x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $|f(x_0)|=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$.

Now, $|f(x_0)|=|x_0^ng(x_0)|$. If $x_0=0$, then we are done. So, let us assume $x_0\neq0$. By the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, $\exists$ a $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $y=x_0^n\leq1$, since $x_0\in[0,1]$.

Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|x^ng(x)|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|f(x_0)|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|yg(y^{\frac{1}{n}})|\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|g(y^{\frac{1}{n}})|=g(1)=0.$

I will be glad if anyone can tell me if I have done any mistake and if so please help me to correct it.

Thank you.

Comment: The reasoning is false, because you did not take into account the fact that $x_0$ depends on $n$.

Comment: How does $x_0$ depend on $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $y$ depends on $n$ so the argument fails. For a correct proof let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\delta >0$ such that $1-\delta \leq x \leq 1$ implies $|g(x)| <\epsilon$ . (This is by continuity of $g$ and the fact that $g(1)=0$). Now $(1-\delta)^{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. If $M=\sup \{|g(x)|: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$ then we see that$|x^{n}g(x)| \leq M(1-\delta)^{n} $ for $0\leq x \leq 1-\delta$. Can  you complete the proof now?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks.